# How to find Java SDK version for a function

Tags: java, sdk, version

I am trying to run an old project in Java using **IntelliJ**. The `ReadMe` file says to use **jdk 1.3** or higher. I tried **jdk 1.4.2** and got some errors:

If I use `jdk 1.3` I get an error for only `String[] t = words.split("_");` function because of missing `split`. I want to know which is the oldest version of the jdk that contains `split` function.

How can I find that?

Comment: The Javadoc tells you when a class or method was added. If the method doesn't say, look at the class. The latest version of IntelliJ will warn you if you try to use a never method/class than your target version.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. When developing you should first prevent the runtime version target and take a look at the JavaDoc

`String#split` is [available since java 4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

You can for sure always check the Java version at runtime by doing this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specifically asked about JDK 1.3 version.You can use [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to break a string into tokens.

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Note:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

Comment: Thanks, however I need the code for `String[] t = words.split("_");`, How can I achieve it in 3.1

Comment: Sorry, I think I mixed two questions with each other, I created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542768/java-split-in-jdk-1-3 for the second part, you may want to move your answer there