# Java WTK cannot use StringTokenizer

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, sun, java-wireless-toolkit

Initially, I was trying to parse a `String` into parts and found `split` method. Then I realized that I cannot use it, because the compiler does not support most of the functions and methods. I thought I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542768/java-split-in-jdk-1-3#answer-38543144) which suggests `StringTokenizer`, but I am still getting **cannot find symbol** error even though `java.util.*` is imported. I am using Java WTK 2.5.2 for CLDC. Do I have to write everything from scratch whenever I get an error or is there anything that I missed? I am not familiar with Java, so any answer will be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
public class Program extends MIDlet implements CommandListener
{
    public Program()
    {
        ...
    }
    public static String[] split(String data, String token)
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this_is_a_test", "_");
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
error: cannot find symbol
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this_is_a_test", "_");
        ^
  symbol:   class StringTokenizer
  location: class Program
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I split strings in J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200746/how-do-i-split-strings-in-j2me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like most of the general functions and methods cannot be used in *micro edition*. So, I had to implement my own case-specific function to solve the problem. Here are some useful links that show what can be used:

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/)

[Tutorial & Examples](https://www.roseindia.net/j2me/)